# Adding Items in Right-Click menu

Tags: c#, .net, windows-shell, windows-explorer

on Windows Explorer, how do I add items on the Right-Click menu?

I would like to create "Move To PATH" item. For example:

I select **ANY** files/folders from Windows Explorer and then click on "Move To D:\Backup\" from Right-Click menu.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc144175%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).
You need to create a registry structure in HKCR.*ext*.

Comment: But I would like to store Paths and Items name in the XML or INI file? What is the solution to that against registry?

Comment: Also when item CLICKED from right-click menu, how to request to MOVE specific folder?